# ExtJS - Grid column list filter options taking time to render

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am having a grid in which there is a column with filter type as List.
Now to populate the options in the filter list i am using store. This store does a API call to get the options that needs to be shown in that filter.

For that column I get around 600 to 800 option values. Now the server responds in few milliseconds but the grid takes time to render these options values.

It takes more than 2mins to render those options as menu items and show it on UI.

How to improve the rendering performance in this use case. When debugged i found that inside Container.add method Ext.resumeLayouts(true) is getting called and it is taking time. In ExtJS documents it is mentioned that resumeLayouts should be used to improve the performance of the rendering.

Is there any way i can improve the performance in this case ?

Comment: Why would you have a menu with 600-800 items?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Ideally we should not have these many options. But the grid for which i am showing the data has use case where applying on some filters results in these many options as the data set on which the grid is shown is huge. Even for 300-400 option items it is taking too much time to render.

Comment: Why would you ever want to show 300 menu options? Who would find that UI useful?

Comment: I agree that it wont be useful. To solve this usability we have left panel along with grid panel, in this left panel we show all the filter with first top 5 options upfront and then we show a Show More link. Once user clicks on Show More link we show a floating panel that has all the options along with a search option.
We are trying to keep this advance filter panel in sync with the columns level filters. But if rendering 300+ menu options is not going to be fast inside column filter menu then we will go with advance filter panel only and disable column level filters.
Thanks for your inputs!